# Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at input location [1,2]

Tags: apex, callout, twilio

I'm getting this return error in this Twilio API call by Saleforce, but I couldn't identify what's wrong, could someone help me?

```
public static Boolean sendMessage(String mobileno , String message){
    
    ResponseWrapper erw;

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    String URL = 'http://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'+System.Label.ACCOUNT+'/Messages.json';
    req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.setEndpoint(URL);
    System.debug('URL >> ' + URL );
    req.setMethod('POST');

    Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(System.Label.ACCOUNT + ':' + System.Label.AUTH_TOKEN);
    String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
    req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

    if(mobileno != null) {
        String jsonString = 'From='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode('whatsapp:+19362336350', 'UTF-8')+
                            '&Body='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(message, 'UTF-8')+
                            '&To='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode('whatsapp:+55'+mobileno+'', 'UTF-8')+'';
        req.setBody(jsonString);

        try {
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
            System.debug(res.getBody());

            if(res.getStatusCode() == 201) {
                return true;
            } else {
                System.debug('Twilio failed >> ' + mobileno);
                erw = (ResponseWrapper) json.deserialize(res.getBody(), ResponseWrapper.class);
                System.debug('Twilio error >> ' + erw);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Error : ' + e);
        }    
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Check the response body in your log, you're probably getting a 404 or 403 page (html) instead of JSON.

Comment: <head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<hr><center>openresty</center>


i am getting this error in html.

Comment: This isn't an error, it's a redirect. You need to check the Location header and follow it if you get a 3xx (300-399) status code. Try calling this in curl or Postman and see where it redirects to. From there, you should be able to figure out what you need to do next.

Answer (score 2):

A 3xx status code is a redirect. You should be able to immediately try again with the new location:

```
try {
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    System.debug(res.getBody());

    // Follow redirect, try again
    // Note: integer division to get just the 3rd number
    if(res.getStatusCode()/100 == 3) {
        req.setEndpoint(res.headers.get('Location'));
        res = http.send(req);
    }
    if(res.getStatusCode() == 201) {
        return true;
    } else {
        System.debug('Twilio failed >> ' + mobileno);
        erw = (ResponseWrapper) json.deserialize(res.getBody(), ResponseWrapper.class);
        System.debug('Twilio error >> ' + erw);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.debug('Error : ' + e);
}
```

You'll probably want to call the API in Postman or curl in order to see where you're being redirected to, and why. It might be an authentication problem or an updated resource URL, or you might be calling the wrong method somehow.

Comment: in postman the same call worked, this part you added gave an error